# Making accepted-answer box greener

Tags: support, status-completed, accepted-answer

Far away from being the most important thread on GIS Meta, but I think it is valid to ask:

Here is a picture that contains an accepted answer in GIS SE and an accepted answer in Stack Overflow.  Sometimes (depending on the light situation), i think is a little difficult to see the green box around accepted answer on GIS.

[image]

**Is it possible to make the accepted-answer box greener, for GIS SE?**

If no, does anyone know a workaround I could use on my desktop/laptop to change this feature without changing to much other settings of colours?

---

I am totally satisfied with @blah238's answer. This is what I am getting now:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The site was designed one way. You want it to look another way. This is what [Cascading Style Sheets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets) (CSS) are for. You can either tweak your user agent (browser) style sheets, or use an extension such as [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/) to manage your style tweaks.

Here is a Stylish style you can use, makes the accepted answer background color a bit more saturated:

```
@-moz-document domain("gis.stackexchange.com") {
    .answered-accepted .mini-counts {
        background-color: rgb(180, 250, 180) !important;
    }
}
```

How did I figure out what to tweak? I just used Firefox's built-in developer tools (e.g. [Page Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector)) to inspect the element I wanted to change, found the CSS rule being applied and tweaked it in-place to my liking before copying it into a new Stylish style.

---

There is also now a [userstyles.org style](http://userstyles.org/styles/91645/gis-stack-exchange-usability-enhancements) incorporating this request. See: [User style for commonly-requested site usability enhancements](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3270/753)

Comment: On the Chrome version you specify the URL/domain in a separate box, so you don't need to include that part. Also make sure to check the Enabled checkbox.

Comment: Great!!! This is what worked for me: `.answered-accepted {
        background-color: rgb(180, 250, 180) !important;
}`

Comment: Just sharing: this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18048479/triangle-background-color-on-accepted-answers-on-se) has an answer which led me to the final code that set the background color for accepted answers equal to Stack Overflow format (it mentions Cross Validated there, but I also applied it for GIS SE).

Answer (score 4):

While CSS can be used by people to enhance their own GIS-SE experience, I think requests such as this one would slightly improve the user experience of anyone who would prefer to use our site without resort to configuration or customisation.