# Change the design of the "Ask Question" button

Tags: feature-request, user-interface

The **Ask Question** button of GIS StackExchange is hard to find compared to StackOverflow (see graphic borrowed from @Mapperz below)

[image]

I propose:

1. Moving the button to the right like on StackOverflow; and/or
2. Changing the design in some other manner to make it stick out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While CSS can be used by people to enhance their own GIS-SE experience, I think requests such as this one make a lot of sense to try and improve the user experience of anyone who would prefer to use our site without resort to configuration or customisation.

Comment: +1 I really don't want to get involved in maintaining customizations of websites. What a nightmare when migrating systems or changing browsers!  And then when SE tweaks something that breaks my customization, I'll have to go into debugging mode just to keep using this site. No thanks; life is too short.

Comment: @whuber, it's really not that hard. I only learned about Stylish myself the other day and had it up and running with the desired tweaks in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @Blah It's not a question of easy or hard.  It's a matter of having to do that extra (annoying) work every time you switch to another machine or--even worse--the target website changes its code. That's not a sustainable model for interacting with the world--not until all your tweaks can be centralized in the cloud and everybody's web pages are guaranteed to remain backwards compatible.  Right.

Comment: userstyles.org itself is a cloud storage system for storing user styles. There are quite a few for SO/SE on there.

Comment: I think anyone who is actually picky enough to care about the color or positioning of some element can also probably be bothered for the all of 2 minutes it takes to install and use a user style someone else has made: http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/q/3270/753

Comment: And only if the change is overwhelmingly accepted should it be made default. Some people don't like change.

Comment: I think it is great that such an easy workaround is available for those who are picky (in this case I'm not :-), but I think we also want new users to see the most visually appealing GUI possible at the outset.  Perhaps we can use +20 votes as a guideline to when overwhelming acceptance has been reached.

Answer (score 5):

So this is the comparison you are talking about:

[image]

This is first instance in 22,000 questions on GIS Stack Exchange where this has been identified.

I believe the tabs could be more prominent - there are users using css changes - on their local browsers to enhance their own GIS-SE experience.

Comment: See http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3252/make-the-accepted-answer-box-greener to make the CSS changes

Comment: +1 for the direct visual comparison, and how to take this into your own hands, but also +1 to the Q, because yes I think the [ Ask ] tab could benefit from some form of emphasizing highlighting as it's not quite the same class as the other items. I've never said anything about it before, but I *have* hunted for the button on occasion.

Answer (score 2):

This is trivial to accomplish with CSS. Using [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/) (see [this answer](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3254/753) for more info), this style works for me:

```
.askquestion {
    float: right !important;
}
```

**Update:** There is also now a [userstyles.org style](http://userstyles.org/styles/91645/gis-stack-exchange-usability-enhancements) incorporating this request. See: [User style for commonly-requested site usability enhancements](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3270/753)