# User style for commonly-requested site usability enhancements

Tags: discussion, design

Recently we've seen a number of requests for usability enhancements to this site. Would there be any interest in creating a community-made [user style](http://userstyles.org)?

This could be used to prototype usability enhancements and demonstrate their worth to the SE administration.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a user style I've created based on the two most recent requests:

[**GIS Stack Exchange Usability Enhancements**](http://userstyles.org/styles/91645/gis-stack-exchange-usability-enhancements)

Currently this incorporates the following enhancement requests:

- [Change the design of the "Ask Question" button](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3261/753)
- [Make the accepted-answer box greener](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3252/753)

You can use this on Chrome or Firefox using the Stylish extension. See the [userstyles.org](http://userstyles.org) homepage for more details.

This style is offered in the public domain so anyone may use/modify/redistribute it without attribution or restriction.

Comment: One more customization you could add, is to set the RSS Feed at the top of the question, using something like this: `#feed-link a {
    position: absolute;
    right: 275px;
    top: 133px;
}`

Comment: Thats a good idea -- however, I think it needs to be done at the DOM level, not with CSS. So a user style for it is out, but a GreaseMonkey script could do it. Personally I would put it just underneath the question menu, e.g. where it says "share, edit ...".

Comment: If you apply the CSS given in my Comment, the link appears to the left of the 'Ask Question' button.

Comment: That illustrates my point, for me it appears to the *right* of the Ask Question button, outside of the main content div, and it moves around undesirably when you zoom in or out or change DPI. That is why it needs to be done at the DOM level.

Answer (score 2):

Many people might have problems with the Black bar at the top.

Some Folks have put up custom stylesheet on meta.stackoverflow.com, which might be useful, to create a custom look. You can have a look at the discussion here: [Gallery of custom styles and/or scripts for the top-bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210041/gallery-of-custom-styles-and-or-scripts-for-the-top-bar)

Comment: Good to know. I don't mind it myself, or at least care enough to bother messing with it.